Remove leaflet canvas layer
I am using the Leaflet Canvas markers plugin and I have successfully achieved creating the canvas markers via a function upon clicking a button.
This is a simplified version of the web app I am creating. In this app the markers and text are generated dynamically so I need the user to be able to click the button repeatedly and the canvas to be redrawn with new markers.
However, I was unable to destroy the original canvas. I have tried map.removeLayer(ciLayer), but that did not help. I also tried ciLayer.clear() and ciLayer.removeMarkers(markers), but even though those methods are mentioned in the plugin documentation, they do not work.
Here is a codepen of the code I have so far. If you click the button, label markers are correctly created, but clicking the button again just adds a new batch without deleting the original ones.
I therefore need to either delete the canvas layer altogether or empty it before generating new markers.
Any help appreciated.
https://codepen.io/jachym/pen/QWXrPZj
The function to add canvas markers:
function addCanvas() {
  window.ciLayer = L.canvasIconLayer({}).addTo(map);

  var icon;
  var img;
  markers = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    img = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svgText(i));
    icon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: img,
      iconSize: [40, 30],
      iconAnchor: [20, 15]
    });
    x = Math.random() * 1.8;
    y = Math.random() * 3.6;
    var marker = L.marker([58.5578 + x, 29.0087 + y], { icon: icon }).bindPopup(
      "I Am "
    );
    markers.push(marker);
  }

  ciLayer.addLayers(markers);
}


before create new markers try to use  the code below to remove the
old markers
 for (i =0; i < markers.length; i++) {
       if (data.id_user == markers[i].options.id_user )  {
      console.log(markers[i].options.id_user) ;    
        map.removeLayer(markers[i]);
        console.log('removed level');
        markers.splice(markers[i],1);
     //  map.setView([data.latitude , data.longitude]); 
     //  break;
        }    
    }

Hope this code can help you  to solve with your adjustments
